# Build error with Bwoken and tuneup_js for iOS UIAutomation tests

Tags: ios, iphone, automated-tests, xcode6, cocoapods

So I've recently been trying to implement a test suite using Bwoken and tuneupjs for my iOS application. My application currently only builds for iOS 7 and is only compatible with 32bit architecture.

When I attempt to run `$ bwoken test` I get this build error:

```
Standard Error:
2014-10-22 14:16:21.980 xcodebuild[94140:3433708]  DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users/sdagostino/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%206.1.db).
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/sdagostino/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-aecacvpqnqgkozgqmkrucotliffv/Build/Intermediates/TestApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TestApp normal x86_64
(1 failure)
Build failed!
Users/sdagostino/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@ios-test-app/gems/bwoken-2.1.0.rc.2/lib/bwoken/build.rb:86:in `compile': Bwoken::BuildFailedError (Bwoken::BuildFailedError)
    from /Users/sdagostino/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@ios-test-app/gems/bwoken-2.1.0.rc.2/lib/bwoken/cli/test.rb:83:in `compile'
    from /Users/sdagostino/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@ios-test-app/gems/bwoken-2.1.0.rc.2/lib/bwoken/cli/test.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Users/sdagostino/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@ios-test-app/gems/bwoken-2.1.0.rc.2/lib/bwoken/cli.rb:58:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sdagostino/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@ios-test-app/gems/bwoken-2.1.0.rc.2/bin/bwoken:3:in `require'
    from /Users/sdagostino/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@ios-test-app/gems/bwoken-2.1.0.rc.2/bin/bwoken:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sdagostino/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@ios-test-app/bin/bwoken:23:in `load'
    from /Users/sdagostino/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@ios-test-app/bin/bwoken:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/sdagostino/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@ios-test-app/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/sdagostino/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@ios-test-app/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

FYI: I can build and run my application fine within Xcode, however I have my simulator set an iPhone 5.

My question is: how can I specify which architecture to build for when building through bwoken and not Xcode?

Here are my dependency files:

Podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'tuneup_js'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'TestApp' do

end

target 'TestAppTests' do

end
```

Gemfile

```
# A sample Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

# gem "rails"
gem 'bwoken', '2.1.0.rc.2'
gem 'cocoapods'
```

- Ruby version: `2.1.0`
- Cocoapods version: `0.34.4`
- Xcode version: 6.1

Thanks in advance for any contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--device <device-name-or-id>` to target a certain device (use `instruments -s devices` to list the available ones). `--scheme` might be useful if you have more than one build schemes.

I also use `--skip-build` while writing the tests.